# AOT Compilation Error Cannot find Module

Tags: angular2-aot

I have an Angular 2 application that I wish to convert to AOT from JIT.
I did the following:
 **Boot.JS**

```
import { enableProdMode }     from '@angular/core'
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../appAot/appModule.ngfactory';
enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory)
 .then(success => console.log(`Bootstrap success`))
 .catch(error => console.log('Filler' + error));
```

**AOT Config**

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "../appAot/node_modules/@types/"
    ],
    "outDir": "../buildJs/"
},

"files": [
    "appModule.ts",
    "app.Routing.ts",
    "boot.ts",
    ...
    "services/searchService.ts",
    "services/titleService.ts",
    "services/uiService.ts",
    "services/validationServices.ts"
],
"exclude": [ "node_modules" ],

"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "../appAot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
}
```

I am using Angular2 4.3.5,Angular2-cli 4.3.5 and Angular2-compiler 4.3.5
The compilation results are generated in the appAot folder. This folder contains all the ngFactories.
Example: searchComponent.ngfactory.ts along with searchComponent.ngsummary.json
The AOT compilation generates the following error:
Error at C:....\searchComponent.ngfactory.ts:20:22 Cannot find module './SearchComponent'
Within SearchComponent.ngFactory.ts at line 20 the following can be found:
import * as i11 from './searchComponent';

This error appears for every import statement.

What am I missing?
Any help would be greately appreciated